# How to get this metric tensor perturbation equation? (Gravitational wave）

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, gravitational-waves

(I need some time to come back to re-edit this post)

LHS of equation 7.37 is gauge invariant

The Twisted H symbol is comoving hubble parameter, the h_ij is metric perturbation, I do not know how to derive equation 7.43, please help me, thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In (7.43), why is $i$ lower on the left but upper on the right? What do the primes mean? What does the $(T)$ mean? What does “has the same structural form” mean?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. It breaks search functionality and doesn't work for blind users. Please don't cut and paste random stuff on the internet without attribution. To make your math get rendered correctly, surround it with dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks I will start learning how to post question properly

Comment: Please post a link to the textbook or notes where you found this problem